# Are function implementations defined inside header file compiled into static library?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, static-libraries

Say we had tons of heasders with classes and impementations in them like this:

```
// header.h
#ifndef MYHEADER
#define MYHEADER
class myClass {
public:
    int one()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int two();
};
#endif // MYHEADER
```

and some cpp files with some function implementations:

```
// header_impl.cpp
#include "header.h"
int myClass::two()
{
    return 2;
}
```

Will into .lib (.a) library bundle get implementation of `int one()` or it will stay in header and compile only in case someone who uses lib and so this header tends to use it in there code (and will be compiled into his code yet would newer appear in .lib (.a) file)?

So are function implementations defined inside header file compiled into static library?

Comment: In general no, because such functions in headers are `inline`. But the call to inlined functions is compiled to inlined code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the function is not used by any of the library functions itself, and no library function takes its address [makes a function pointer], then the compiler has no reason to make a "real function" of it. Of course, since inlining is really a question of "compiler decides", it's entirely possible that the compiler decides to NOT use the function inline, and in fact make one in the object file where it is compiled.

But in general, for small functions, no, it will only exist as source code in the header, and then get inlined wherever it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, in that a `cpp` almost definitely includes that header within your static library. Generally just because it's defined in the class doesn't force it to be inline, but it does definitely specify that the function has an ODR exception (which I think I called inline linkage; More on that later). So, depending on the function and it's use from within the static library it may or may not have an actual definition, depending on if the compiler inlined it and if it's being used at all.

If the compiler decided not to inline your function, when you `#include` that header from a `exe` which links with the static library you might think it should then get defined again, and break the one definition rule. But, you'd be wrong. Because the fact that the method is defined within the class body marks the function as having an ODR expection. Ultimately it's up to the compiler which definition it will choose (the one in the static library or the one in the `exe`/whatever). Likely it will choose the first one it sees.

Note: You can achieve the ODR exception by defining the function outside of the class body and using the `inline` keyword.